# How do you subtract Dates in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

My heart is bleeding internally after having to go so deep to subtract two dates to calculate the span in number of days:

```
    GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    c1.set(2000, 1, 1);
    c2.set(2010,1, 1);
    long span = c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis();
    GregorianCalendar c3 = new GregorianCalendar();
    c3.setTimeInMillis(span);
    long numberOfMSInADay = 1000*60*60*24;
    System.out.println(c3.getTimeInMillis() / numberOfMSInADay); //3653
```

where it's only 2 lines of code in .NET, or any modern language you name.

Is this atrocious of java? Or is there a hidden method I should know?

Instead of using GregorianCalendar, is it okay to use Date class in util? If so, should I watch out for subtle things like the year 1970?

Thanks

Comment: why do you use c3? Afaik you could leave out at least the two lines for c3 ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's indeed one of the biggest epic failures in the standard Java API. Have a bit of patience, then you'll get your solution in flavor of the new Date and Time API specified by [JSR 310 / ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/) which is (most likely) going to be included in the upcoming Java 8.

Until then, you can get away with [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int days = Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays();
```

Its creator, Stephen Colebourne, is by the way the guy behind JSR 310, so it'll look much similar.

Comment: I have a small project and need it in only a few places. Coming anew from .NET, I am just a bit infuriated and frustrated at java. Thanks for the confirmation, though.

Comment: You could also create an utility method and hide it far away in the depths of your code so that you won't be directly bothered by the ugly Calendar API ;)

Comment: Did JSR 310 ever see the day ?

Comment: @James: not in Java 7. It will likely be in Java 8, see also http://blog.joda.org/2010/12/what-about-jsr-310_153.html (note: posted 4 months after this answer). I updated the links in my answer.

Comment: It has been implemented in Java 8 using Period..
http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/number-of-days-between-two-dates/

Answer (score 18):

You can use the following approach:

```
SimpleDateFormat formater=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

long d1=formater.parse("2001-1-1").getTime();
long d2=formater.parse("2001-1-2").getTime();

System.out.println(Math.abs((d1-d2)/(1000*60*60*24)));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you deal with dates it is a good idea to look at the joda time library for a more sane Date  manipulation model.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Well you can remove the third calendar instance.

```
GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
c1.set(2000, 1, 1);
c2.set(2010,1, 1);
c2.add(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, -1 * c1.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: I don't think GregorianCalendar is immutable, so if I should use c2 later again, I sort of like to have it the value as it was defined initially.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic approach,

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date beginDate = dateFormat.parse("2013-11-29");
Date endDate = dateFormat.parse("2013-12-4");

Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
beginCalendar.setTime(beginDate);

Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
endCalendar.setTime(endDate);
```

There is simple way to implement it. We can use Calendar.add method with loop. The minus days between beginDate and endDate, and ***the implemented code as below***,

```
int minusDays = 0;
while (true) {
  minusDays++;

  // Day increasing by 1
  beginCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

  if (dateFormat.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).
            equals(dateFormat.format(endCalendar).getTime())) {
    break;
  }
}
System.out.println("The subtraction between two days is " + (minusDays + 1));**
```

Comment: Excellent use of the word "substractation" :)