# Date subtraction in java

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you subtract Dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java)

I am creating java desktop application. In that application user give some date inputs. so i use 3party library "jCalendar.jar". for validation i want to subtract two dates. is there any way to **subtract two dates in java?**

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You should look into JodaTime: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ and also at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Java Date or Java Calendar, then you could use something like:

```
Calendar firstOperand = new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar secondOperand = new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar result = new GregorianCalendar();

result.setTimeInMillis(firstOperand.getTimeInMillis() - secondOperand.getTimeInMillis());
```

edit: 
As pointed in the comments, storing the result in a calendar wouldn't make much sense. You can still use the milliseconds returned for your operations.

If possible you could also use a library to handle this, like [JODA](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html).

It allows you to get the number of [seconds](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html#secondsBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-)/[minutes](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#minutesBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-)/[days](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-)/[months](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Months.html#monthsBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-)/[etc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/) from between two dates and more things.

Comment: This is a bit strange. Suppose I subtract 5 August 2012, 12:34 from 13 August 2012, 15:41 and put the result in a `Calendar`. What date would you expect the `Calendar` to be set on? The result of subtracting two dates is an amount of time, not a moment in time. `Calendar` is not suited to holding an amount of time.

Comment: You are right, on second though is a bit strange, but is what i though on that moment, still he can use the milliseconds on a different way instead of setting on the Calendar.

Comment: This helps my work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't give toomuch, you can look at open source: try [JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html).

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int noOfdays = Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), the de-facto standard for date handling in Java. Given two `java.util.Dates`, `javaDate1`, and `javaDate2`:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(javaDate1);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(javaDate2);

Period diff = new Period(d1, d2);
```

You can now query the `diff` object for the difference, split into it's constituent components (years, months, days, etc.). See the Joda Time [period guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.util.GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Create an instance of this class then call the setTime() method to set your date. Finally use the methods of this class.