# Convert IST to US timezones considering the daylight saving time in java

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I have a date-time in IST. I want to convert it to US timezones based on input considering the daylight saving time,
if there is  daylight saving time for the given date-time in java.
This is what i tried

```
function convert(Date dt,int toTimeZoneId){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt); // Geting time in IST

//Converted to GMT and set in cal

switch(toTimeZoneId){
    case 1: tzTarget = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Adak"); 
        offset = -10;
        break;
    case 2: tzTarget = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Anchorage"); 
        offset = -9;
        break;
    case 3: tzTarget = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"); 
        offset = -8;
        break;

    case 4: tzTarget = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Denver");
        offset = -7;
        break;
    case 5: tzTarget = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
        offset = -6;
        break;
    case 6: tzTarget = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        offset = -5;
        break;
}
//converting from GMT to US timezones based on offset and dst
cal.setTimeZone(tzTarget);
dst = tzTarget.getDSTSavings();
dst = dst/3600000;
offset = offset + dst;
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, offset);

Date date = cal.getTime();

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date));
```

}

Comment: Where is the code that you tried ?

Comment: So you want to convert it to CDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just convert a given date to different time zones, you need to create the date formatter with appropriate time zone. A date instance is just a long value relative to epoch; it doesn't have time zone information. So we aren't converting it to a different time zone, we are just representing it in different time zones. That is why we need time zone information when we want to create a string representation of the date instance.

Here's some code to illustrate the above. I've just added the time zone to your date format string to make things clear.

```
/*
 * Converts a specified time to different time zones
 */
public void convert(Date dt) {
    // This prints: Date with default formatter: 2013-03-14 22:00:12 PDT
    // As my machine is in PDT time zone
    System.out.println("Date with default formatter: " + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").format(dt));

    // This prints: Date with IST time zone formatter: 2013-03-15 10:30:12 GMT+05:30
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530");
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
    String dateIST = sdf.format(dt);
    System.out.println("Date with IST time zone formatter: " + dateIST);

    // This prints: Date CST time zone formatter: 2013-03-15 00:00:12 CDT        
    tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
    System.out.println("Date CST time zone formatter: " + sdf.format(dt));
}
```

I think this is what you are trying to do - convert a given time to different time zones. To do that I don't think you need to add/subtract any offset, as you just want the *same* time represented in a different time zone and the `TimeZone` instance should be able to take care of that during formatting.

As for daylight saving, the `TimeZone` should be able to take care of that as well. If you notice in my example code, I've used `CST` to create `TimeZone` instance and `CST` is "GMT -06 hours". But the output it gives is in `CDT`, which is "GMT -05 hours", because this time zone instance uses daylight saving. So by using the appropriate time zone you should be able to handle daylight saving as well.

Comment: public void convert(Date dt){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt); // Geting time in IST
  
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"),Locale.US);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
  
Date date = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date));} This is what i tried. But i got the output as the same datetime  which i have given as the input... !!!

Comment: @akhilgm89, you are getting the same date string because you are using `SimpleDateFormat` instance with default time zone, which will be your system's time zone. A `Date` instance is just a long value denoting milliseconds since epoch; it does not contain time zone information. When you create string representations, you need to specify the timezone to use. I've edited my post to explain this with code. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) allows you create dates with timezones. Unfortunately, addition and subtraction suck from there. ([How do you subtract Dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526485/90322))

Since you're converting between two timezones, you can also make use of [java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) and use the difference of `tz1.getOffset(date) - tz2.getOffset(date)`. Mind the ordering when doing subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) makes this much easier. Or try the new java.time package in Java 8.

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3. Search StackOverflow for many more examples.

India time…

```
DateTimeZone timeZone_India = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = new DateTime( date, timeZone_India );
```

Adjusting the same moment for display as New York time…

```
DateTimeZone timeZone_NewYork = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime dateTimeNewYork = dateTimeIndia.withZone( timeZone_NewYork ); // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

Still the same moment, but in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (no time zone offset).

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

## Use Proper Time Zone Names

Avoid using 3-4 letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. Your `IST` for example can mean either Irish Standard Time or India Standard Time. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).