# Subtracting two dates gives error "The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Date, java.util.Date"

Tags: java, date

In below code

1. on subtracting **date** from a **date** giving this error `"The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Date, java.util.Date"`
2. variable **currentDate** is a `String`; why I couldn't save it in `Date` variable like this 
   `Date currentDate = ddmmyy.format(new Date());` , does `.format` function returns `String`?

   ```
   public class AgeCalculator {

     public static SimpleDateFormat ddmmyy=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   String dob = "05/01/1993";
   Date mod_date =  ddmmyy.parse(dob);
   String currentDate = ddmmyy.format(new Date());
   Date mod_currentDate = ddmmyy.parse(currentDate);
   int days = mod_currentDate-mod_date;

    }


   }
   ```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java)

Comment: what should I look here, that doesnt answer my question...

Answer (score 2):

First change `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyyy` as `mm`-Minute in hour and `MM`-Month in year

```
SimpleDateFormat ddmmyy=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dob = "21/07/2014";
Date mod_date =  ddmmyy.parse(dob);
String currentDate = ddmmyy.format(new Date());
Date mod_currentDate = ddmmyy.parse(currentDate);
```

It shall give you difference between them in milliseconds and its type is `long`

```
long differenceInMillis = mod_currentDate.getTime()-mod_date.getTime();
```

fnally get the number of days from milliseconds

```
int days = (int) (differenceInMillis / (1000*60*60*24));
System.out.println(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look here; [Java, Calculate the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)
Your mod_currentDate returns the 22th of January instead of July because of the fact you use mm instead of MM.

```
public class AgeCalculator  {
     public static SimpleDateFormat ddmmyy=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String dob = "05/01/1993";
      Date mod_date =  ddmmyy.parse(dob);
      Date currentDate = new Date();
      int days = daysBetween(mod_date,currentDate);
      System.out.println("Get the amount of days between " + mod_date + " and " + currentDate);
      System.out.println("Days= "+ days); 
       }

      public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
        return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Get the amount of days between Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 CET 1993 and Tue Jul 22 16:19:02 CEST 2014
Days= 7868
```