# Subtract Dates and show result in jTextField

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using `jdatechooser` in Netbeans and I have two dates as output
`date1 = 3/25/17`
`date2 = 3/30/17`

I want a way of subtracting this two dates to get differece in days `e.g: 3 Days`  and put my results into a `jtexftield`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you subtract Dates in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make an attempt and post here a [MCVE] version of your attempt to solve it

Comment: I have used `joda-time` now I am getting error : `Invalid format: "3/27/17" is malformed at "/27/17"`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse you date to `LocaDate` and then calculate difference using `Period`:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy");
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("3/25/17",dateTimeFormatter);
LocalDate  end = LocalDate.parse("3/30/17",dateTimeFormatter);
System.out.println(Period.between(start,end).getDays());
```

For pre `java-8` code please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java)